# Tag pages footer thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress

So here's the thing.

By default on my wordpress theme the Numbered navigation on Tag pages won't work. Only on Tag pages. So a friend solved it for me. He did it by putting this code in my functions.php:

```
    add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'Pricerr_g_query_post_type');
function Pricerr_g_query_post_type($query) {
  if(is_tag()) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
 if($post_type)
     $post_type = $post_type;
 else
     $post_type = array('post','job');
    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
 return $query;
    }
}
```

Now, when that solution is implemented the Thumbnails for my posts and widgets on the Tag pages breaks. So my friend fixed it by adding this code in functions.php:

```
<? $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img width="102" height="72" class="<?php echo $img_class; ?>" 
                src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" /></a>
```

So that fixes the Post thumbnails on the Tag pages, but the Widgets thumbnails (latest posts, featured posts) still won't show.

You can see what I'm talking about on this page. Scroll down and see the footer widgets: http://bit.ly/1PfmNjM

Hope someone can help. Thank you.